# How do I find the points at which the following functions intersect? And how many times do they intersect?

Tags: calculus

I have a function $f(x) = 4x^3 − 2x^2 − 4x − 2 $
And a line $y = 4x -1$
And I need to know where they intersect, I know that I have to do $4x^3 − 2x^2 − 4x − 2 = 4x -1$
But I can't find the x-values and I'm not allowed to use graphs.
As for how many times they intersect, I think it's three because the polynomial is third degree

Comment: Are you sure about those functions? The equation that you reached has no simple solution.

Comment: I'm sure of it, which happens to be why i'm stumped.

Comment: Probably is there a typo?

Comment: Could the Intermediate Value Theorem help here?

Comment: @MathLove `I think it's three because the polynomial is third degree`. Yes but it's not necessary that all the three are real. You may even get (not for this question) pairs of complex conjugate roots. In that case they **wouldn't intersect the real axis thrice**, at least not in the conventional way.

Answer (score 2):

The 
[discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_discriminant)
of the cubic $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is

\begin{align} 
\Delta(a,b,c,d) &=18abcd-4b^3d+b^2c^2-4ac^3-27a^2d^2
,
\end{align}

in particular for the cubic 
\begin{align} 
4x^3-2x^2-8x-1
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
the discriminant is
\begin{align} 
\Delta(4,-2,-8,-1)&=6832>0
,
\end{align}

hence, \eqref{1} has three distinct real roots.

Dividing \eqref{1} by $4$
and substituting $t+\tfrac16$ for $x$, we get
a reduced cubic equation

\begin{align} 
t^3+pt+q=&0
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\text{where}\quad
p&=-\tfrac{25}{12}
,\quad
q=-\tfrac{16}{27}
.
\end{align}

Applying 
[Trigonometric solution for three real roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots)
to \eqref{2},
we can find the roots as
\begin{align}
t_k&=
2\sqrt{-\frac{p}3}
\cos\left(\frac1{3}\arccos 
\left({\frac{3q}{2p}}\sqrt{-\frac3p}\right)
-\frac{2\pi k}3\right)
\quad \text{for}\quad k=0,1,2
,\\
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
t_0&=\phantom{-}\tfrac53\cos(\tfrac13\arccos(\tfrac{64}{125}))
\approx  1.56878
,\\
t_1&=-\tfrac53\cos(\tfrac13\arccos(\tfrac{64}{125})+\tfrac\pi3)
\approx -0.29702
,\\
t_2&=-\tfrac53\sin(\tfrac13\arccos(\tfrac{64}{125})+\tfrac\pi6)
\approx -1.27176
.
\end{align}

Then the corresponding roots of \eqref{1} are

\begin{align} 
x_0&=t_0+\tfrac16\approx 1.73545
,\\
x_1&=t_1+\tfrac16\approx -0.13036
,\\
x_2&=t_2+\tfrac16\approx -1.10509
.
\end{align}

Comment: +1. Nice solution. I didn't know that it could be this simple for distinct real roots.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

**Method 1:** You essentially need the root of:

$$4x^3-2x^2-8x-1=0$$

If you use [Descartes' Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs), you can see that the above equation has **a positive real root** and **two negative real roots**.

So this tells you that you have three **real** roots and hence three intersections.

Now finding them is difficult without a graph so you may use [Newton Raphson's method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) for each root or you may get an accurate root and you could factor it out to get the other roots but that would be pretty lengthy.

You should notice that the product of the roots: $$x_1*x_2*x_3=\frac{-(-1)}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Also sum of the roots: $$x_1+x_2+x_3=\frac{-(-2)}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$$

In case you are using *Newton Raphson's method* you could use the above equations for the initial three *good guesses* required for the three roots.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

**Method 2**: you could take: $$y=x-\frac{1}{6}$$

This will eliminate the quadratic term and reduce the equation to:

$$y^3 - \frac{25 y}{12} - \frac {16}{27} = 0$$

For this equation we have a wicked formula known as the *Cubic Formula*. You can find the formula and similar methods here at [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients).